# Questions on compund nouns in the form of 'A of B'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, singular-vs-plural, nouns

> In this forest, we have ten different types of trees. Each type of trees needs a specific type of fertilizers. The choice of fertilizers is depending on the type of trees.

Hi, I don't know when to use 'the' in the noun formation following phrases, I have given an example above, not sure if it is grammatically correct. And It would be very helpful if you can create a few examples to cover the ones not used in the example above.

- types of trees
- the types of trees
- types of the trees
- the types of the trees

Comment: In order: ten different types of trees, each type of tree needs, depending on the type of tree.

Comment: In your example, the middle sentence should read "Each type of tree needs a specific type of fertilizer" - both "tree" and "fertilizer" should be singular not plural there.

Comment: @EdwardBarnard can you tell me why the "tree" and "fertilizer" should be singular? I figure one 'type' can include more than one tree/fertilizer (number-wise), that's why I used the plural form...

Comment: "types of trees" - "there are six types of trees near my house" is correct. We are referring to more than one type. "Our most common type of tree is silver maple. We have seven silver maple trees near my house". A specific type (of tree, of fertilizer) is singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking which of these is correct:

```
- types of trees
- the types of trees
- types of the trees
- the types of the trees
```

The answer depends on context, as all of these could be used in different contexts. The thing to note is that whenever you bring in the definite article "the" you are referring either to *one specific* thing, or *a specific group*.

If you say *the trees* then you must be referring to a particular set of trees - perhaps only the trees contained in one particular area. To use this in context you should have already named that area.

Similarly, if you say *the types* then you must be referring to a particular set of tree-types made clear by the wider context of what you are saying.

For example:

> I know the types of all the trees in the New Forest.

This is okay because you are saying that your knowledge covers a specific set of types from a specific set of trees (the ones contained in the New Forest).

In your quotation though, I would make some changes:

> In this forest, we have ten different types of <s>trees</s> tree. Each type of <s>trees</s> tree needs a specific type of <s>fertilizers</s> fertilizer. The choice of <s>fertilizers is depending</s> fertiliser depends on the type of <s>trees</s> tree.

As a tree can only be of one "type", so *tree* should be singular. "Fertilizer" should also be singular because you will only use one type of fertilizer per tree.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I think according to your example, in my quotation, it should be 'ten different types of trees', not tree, as I have specified the trees are 'in this forest'. Besides, I am still struggling to understand the singular form of fertilizer and tree in the following sentences. So, is it true that, for example, if two types of fertilizers can be applied to a tree, we can say ‘The choice of fertilizers depends on the type of tree.’

Comment: @Elizabeth No, because you are counting the types, not the trees. ;)

Comment: Which one is wrong? 'ten different types of trees?' or 'the choice of fertilizers'. if you are referring to the former, I have also found a lot of examples like 'there are 20 types of men in the world' on the internet... if you are referring to the latter, hmmm, can you give me an example, under what circumstance I can use 'the choice of fertilizers'? thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @Elizabeth I said these are the changes I would make. To be honest, after looking at some examples it seems both are used, perhaps idiomatically? But I've always understood that it should be singular. For example, you might say "types of people", but you can't flip that around and say "people types" like you can with "tree types" or "dog breeds"... you would more likely say "person types", If you said "dogs breeds" it sounds like a dog can have more than one breed.

Comment: Yes, both types exist. Thank you so much for your help!